# Find $a$ if $T:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ is diagonalizable and $T(1,1,1)=(1,1,1), T(1,0,1)=(-3,0,-3), T(1,1,-1)=(a+1,a+1,a-1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

> Find $a$ if $T:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ is diagonalizable and $T(1,1,1)=(1,1,1), T(1,0,1)=(-3,0,-3), T(1,1,-1)=(a+1,a+1,a-1)$.

$B=((1,1,1),(1,0,1),(1,1,-1))$ is a basis for $T$.

Then:
$$
[T]_B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&a\\0&-3&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then we can find the multiplicities and find out that $a$ has to be $0$.

**How did we get to** $[T]_B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard theory in linear algebra, how to find the matrix of linear transformation.

$$T((1,1,1))=(1,1,1)=1.(1,1,1)+0.(1,0,1)+0.(1,1,-1)$$, then the coefficient columnwise gives you the first column. similarly do for the others

Like
$$T((1,0,1))=(-3,0,-3)=0.(1,1,1)+-3.(1,0,1)+0.(1,1,-1)$$.
This gives you the second column.. and so on and so forth

Comment: The only thing I'm confused is that in for example $T(1,0,1)=(-3,0,-3)$, $(-3,0,-3)$ is already an image. So is it only an image according to the standard (canonical) basis right now? So in order to convert it according to vector coordinates we need to do this process?

Comment: I didn't undrstand your confusion. See you are calculating the matrix by taking the ordered basis $B$(as you have written)  on both sides. That is what it means to write $[T]_{B}$. If you have to calculate the matrix by taking $B$ in the domain side and let's say the standard basis say $C$ in the co-domain side then we should write $[T]_{B}^{C}$. But then you have to express each image corresponding to the element in $B$ as linear combinations of the elements of $C$.